# Sending argument through URL with a Werkzeug API

Tags: python, werkzeug

I am new to Werkzeug and start with a simple case : an URL where a name will be given and a 'Hello "name"' to be displayed,

I am on macOS 10.14, installed all the python libraries requested.

The python script is

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

@Request.application
def application(environ, start_response):
    request = Request(environ)
    text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name', 'World')
    response = Response(text, mimetype='text/plain')
    return response(environ, start_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 4000, application)
```

and runs through

```
python shortly_3.py


 * Running on http://localhost:4000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2018 11:45:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The URL should then be something like

```
 http://localhost:4000/
```

plus a name parameter

I have tried

```
 http://localhost:4000?name=toto
```

but get the error

```
Error on request:
TypeError: application() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The way arguments are passed to the application seems fine, and the run_simple command does not show additional ways to pass arguments.

How can I pass the name argument throught the URL?

If I replace this call

```
  text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name')
```

by this one

```
  text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name', 'World')
```

The following fetching still fails with the same error

```
http://localhost:4000?name=toto
```

Comment: Try changing `text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name', 'World')` with `text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name')`

Comment: Thanks, I just gave a try and updated the post

Comment: Look at what they do in http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/tutorial/. There always is a `create_app()` function that returns an object, and that object is given to `run_simple()`, not the `application()` function itself.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak I am having a look. It is quite confusing as in the example with "Hello name" given earlier in the same page, they call the application without the create_app().

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete script I finally came with (Thanks to Tomalak for pointing me the create_app() function)

```
import os
import redis
import urlparse
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from werkzeug.routing import Map, Rule
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException, NotFound
from werkzeug.wsgi import SharedDataMiddleware
from werkzeug.utils import redirect
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

class Shortly(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.redis = redis.Redis(config['redis_host'], config['redis_port'])

    def dispatch_request(self, environ, request):
        request = Request(environ)
        text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name')
        response = Response(text, mimetype='text/plain')
        return response

    def wsgi_app(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        response = self.dispatch_request(environ,request)
        return response(environ, start_response)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)


def create_app(redis_host='localhost', redis_port=6379, with_static=True):
    app = Shortly({
        'redis_host':       redis_host,
        'redis_port':       redis_port
    })
    if with_static:
        app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
            '/static':  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
        })
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    app = create_app()
    run_simple('127.0.0.1', 5000, app, use_debugger=True, use_reloader=True)
```

In a browser with

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=toto
```

gives

```
Hello toto
```

as wished